# How to get the current View from PagerAdapter from a certain position?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have created a custom class extending `PagerAdapter`that represents my adapter to a `ViewPager` in which I slide through `Views` (***not Fragments***).

What my problem really is, is that I don't know how to get the current View that I have add to the adapter earlier so that I can follow a certain procedure with it.

The `PagerAdapter` only provides `instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)` method that returns an `Object` and with my implementation, it returns a `View`.

Is this the right method to call to get the `View` in the current position? And if **Yes**, what I pass as a `container` argument?

Thank you in advance!

References:

**SequenceAdapter.java**

```
public class SequenceAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<View> mList;

public SequenceAdapter(){
    this.mList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void add(View viewGroup){
    mList.add(mList.size(), viewGroup);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = mList.get(position);
    container.addView(view, position);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PagerAdapter` subclass is modeling the views required by the `ViewPager`, so similar to a `ListView`, you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Here's where it gets weird, though:  The `ViewPager` will then ask your adapter where all the current pages go.  This is handled with the override to `getItemPosition()`.  Returning POSITION_NONE will tell the `ViewPager` that the view at that page index is no longer valid, after which it will call `instantiateItem()` to get an updated view.

So rather than trying to get a view you already instantiated (which may not even exist if the user has swiped a couple pages away from it), just tell the `ViewPager` that the view isn't valid anymore and hand it the updated view.

Here's one thing you could do with your adapter:

```
public class SequenceAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<View> mList;

    /** List of all the views/positions that have changed since last update */
    private List<Integer> mChanged;

    public SequenceAdapter(){
        this.mList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mChanged = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(View viewGroup){
        mList.add(mList.size(), viewGroup);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View get(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    public void update(View view, int position) {
        mList.set(position, view);
        mChanged.add(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        int position = (Integer) object;
        return view == mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = mList.get(position);
        container.addView(view, position);
        return new Integer(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        int position = (Integer) object;
        return mChanged.contains(position) ? POSITION_NONE : position;
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(ViewGroup container) {
        mChanged.clear();
    }

}
```

Note that I changed your reference object to be an Integer with the position of the view, rather than the view itself.  This makes things a little easier.

So with the `get()` method you can access the view, then update it with `update()`.  Once you update a view, if it's currently in the `ViewPager` you should see `getItemPosition()` being called.  If POSITION_NONE is returned, you should get an `instantiateItem()` call for that position.  Because of the way `ViewPager` updates with multiple calls to the adapter, it has to tell you when it's finished, so you override `finishUpdate()` to clear the positions marked as changed.

Comment: Right. So in terms of code..Can you give me a piece of example?

Comment: In order for me to post any code that would be at all useful, I would need to reference your existing code.  Updating your question with your current code would be helpful.

Comment: Which one? The Adapter reference?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Not 100% sure it will work since I just typed it in without an IDE, but have a look and see if it works for you.